# Django template for loop checkboxes with same 'name', and then wanting to delete multiple instances

Tags: django, django-templates

So in my Django template I have the following:

```
{% for maillist in maillists %}
<li><input type='checkbox' name='listremove' value='{{maillist}}' id='{{maillist}}' />
<span><label class='list' for='{{maillist}}'>{{maillist}}</label></span></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Which prints out a list of the members on the webpage, each with a checkbox next to them.

When I want to delete members I use a view in views.py

```
if request.POST.get('listremove'):
    for maillist in request.POST.get('listremove'):
        members_to_delete.append(person.email)
```

`members_to_delete` then gets passed to a function which performs the deletion. My problem is that I am unable to delete multiple instances at once - i.e. I think what is happening that `listremove` is only ever one maillist.

I did try `name` = `{{maillist}}}` for each result of the iteration in the template but it isn't as nice as using `listremove` and there is a chance that `{{maillist}}` might get picked up from one of the other forms on the page (when I don't actually want to delete it)....Does anybody have any idea if there's a neat way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `request.POST.getlist('listremove')` to get all the checked items.